# Node.js: It is possible to convert a BLOB into file and open it with default application using shell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

using [shell](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/shell) we can open file by its default application. But it is possible to a `blob` that is converted into file?

```js
var fileurl = ''; //url of a file, example is docx file.
var filename = $(this).text().replace(/^\s+/g, '');

$.ajax({
        url: fileurl,
        method: 'GET',
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'blob'
        },
        success: function (data) {
          //convert the blob into file
          var file = new File([data], filename, {type: data.type, lastModified: Date.now()});
          const {shell} = require('electron');
          shell.openItem(file); //open the converted file with it's default application
        }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I tried to convert the blob into file thinking maybe it will work but it fail and the error says `Error processing argument at index 0, conversion failure from #<File>`.

Answer (score 0):

Electron's `shell.openItem(filepath:string)` explicitly requires path to existing local file. https://electronjs.org/docs/api/shell#shellopenitemfullpath

Unless you save files into some temp location, you can't pass blobs directly.